# Basic security questions OF ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, security

I know that these are very basic questions.  But, would like to get clarified (or know more information) about the following:

1. Once the user logs in, a cookie (I guess it is forms authentication cookie) gets stored at client and the same will be passed for subsequent requests
2. How does ASP.NET persist logged in user details across requests (I know, it does not fetch those details every time from database).  Is it in session or cache or any other mechanism.
3. How does ASP.NET know on how to map a cookie against the respective user details persisted?
4. Does ASP.NET pull roles during authentication phase (say if role provider is setup) and persist them as well?
5. Imagine that the expiry date of (persistant) cookie is set to 7 days.  Next day, when the user tries to login, I am thinking that it is going to fetch user information from database.  How does ASP.NET understand that it has to fetch same user details?

Does any of the above change in membership API of new ASP.NET Identity (of .NET 4.5).  I am not taking claims, external etc. identities into account.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The information is stored in an encrypted cookie, yes.
2. The user details are in the cookie - but encrypted with a key that only the server knows so it is safe to let the browser send it back, the browser won't be able to change the user details.
3. It's all in the cookie.
4. In normal forms auth the roles are not part of the cookie, but stored somewhere else. With the new SessionAuthenticationModule the roles are part of the cookie.
5. It's all in the cookie.